# Do you consider this as connected speech in American accent

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I am trying to learn an American accent. I don't know if what I am saying is considered connected speech.

I uploaded the recording here:

NOTE: The link given by the OP to the referenced sound file has been removed for the reason given below. It remains in the comments to the question.

**WARNING** This link goes to a site that uses pop-under scam advertising that tries to convince you that your web browser and/or Flash plug-in need to be updated.

I won't write the sentence that I said. If you couldn't recognize what I was saying, kindly tell me.

Comment: I know what you said, but it was very difficult to recognize the word before *out*.  (I won't say it here so I don't give it away for anyone else.)

Comment: We discussed your recording in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/conversation/listening

Comment: @snailboat I tried to join the chat but I couldn't. it is ended, isn't?

Comment: Unable to get the file. The page requires Google Ads to be enabled.

Comment: @TRomano okay i upload it again here http://www.megafileupload.com/2zJN/Record_0002.wav

Comment: @TRomano and this is another link too http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=67835939431630556296 if these links don't work, kindly tell me

Comment: I had a more difficult time understanding this sentence, at least in part because it came with no context so I had no idea what I was supposed to be hearing.  To my ear the vowels were a bit off, particularly in the word before "out," as mentioned by @snailboat.  That said, you did join that word with "out" in much the way that an American would.

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli: The sentence you've chosen does not lend itself to  slurring of words and "connected speech".  It asks to be delivered in a slow and measured manner, with proper intonation patterns to demarcate the parenthetic phrase "scenes changing every eleven seconds".  Try this: http://learningenglish.voanews.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link to the recording seems to have died, rendering the question meaningless.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the updated link to the sound file that works properly. Marco (and @TRo): I think you misunderstand the meaning of "connected speech", which I place in quotes here because  Pretty much all natural speech is connected speech. Speech is, esentially and normally, continuous streams of sounds (and silence).

Comment: @JimReynolds Unfortunately, that link goes to a site with some very shady advertising. I've added a warning to the question but I wonder if we should delete the link completely.

Comment: What's that free website that you can upload sound bytes to? I forgot the name...

Comment: You are probably referring to soundcloud.com. Several of us chatting believe that it is less likely to cause problems for visitors or users than other file-sharing sites which may not have an established reputation. dropbox.com might be another good alternative, as may google drive.

Comment: Marco, you may wish to bring your pronunciation questions to this chatroom: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/the-english-learning-cabin. We like to talk about pronunciation there in more detail. I, for one, would not mind making recordings of my own Standard American accent, at least occasionally, for you to compare to. If you want to submit files here, it might be better to use a more established file sharing service.

Comment: @Jim Reynolds: I do understand that speech is a continuous succession of sounds and silences.  Marco, IMO, is not paying close enough attention to the *syntactic* pauses, to phrase-intonations, and to vowel quality, and too much attention (at this point) to how adjacent phones can blend together.  No disrespect to Marco intended, but his choice of exemplars for American-accent emulation, coupled with complex sentences like the one he is speaking here, with its parenthetic clause, is  like The Fonz occupying the anchor desk at ABC news. I am trying to give him a wider range of accent exemplars.

Comment: @TRo OK. I think that the term "connected speech" probably has a number of common senses. I shouldn't have made that kind of suggestion. And The Fonz at ABC news: *lol.*  :-)

Comment: But "connected speech" has a specific meaning here.  It refers to the differences between (1) pronouncing words together as a sentence in normal speech and (2) pronouncing each word independently, as you hear when you click the pronunciation link in an electronic dictionary.

Comment: @sna Yes. Well, when there was a comment above that a sentence "doesn't lend itself to 'slurring of words' and 'connected speech,'" I concluded that TRomano didn't define the concept as I do. I thought it might be helpful to call attention to that and try to define the term--if somewhat clumsily as a non-expert. But after his response, I thought that another purpose could be served by simply recognizing that some of us may be using the term to express different ideas. It provokes some interesting questions, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [recording of my voice](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_hivi_ChoizaWR1OXlfRjhKbms/view?usp=sharing) (General American / Standard American English) repeating the speech that you are working on from https://youtu.be/mu-eaxlA5jo

This [second recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_hivi_ChoizMXJSVExSSElnSTA/view?usp=sharing) may help to put your attention on the places where I think you sound the most different than me. There are only three important places!

The vowel sound you make in frAn is incorrect.

Frantic Fran fran fran an an an fran fran tic

. . . 11 seconds ON AVERAGE

Zoned out  Zo Zo Zo Zo Zo Zo Zon dout Zon-dout Zon-dout.